# Android GPS tracker return everytime 0 for the longitude and latitude

Tags: android, gps, location

I m trying to get the user location using the service that i call in my mainActivity.I believe i made already all the work needed but the problem i get back everytime 0 for the longitude and 0 for  latitude ! 
I added user permission too but its not working !
This is the service class:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener{

private final Context context;

boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;

double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }

            if(isGPSEnabled) {
                if(location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if(locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if(locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if(location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if(location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.location = location;
    getLatitude();
    getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

and this is how i call it in the mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GPSTracker gps;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        Log.v("Your LOCATION is -" + "Lat:", latitude + "Long: " + longitude  );
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Your LOCATION is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                        + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }





}
}
```

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: Have you tried `String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude)`

Comment: http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Comment: @JoelFazio yes i did but it returns 0 as always :/

Comment: @DanielNugent i tried that already but it wont work maybe because i didnt know how to call it on the mainActivity or how it works.If you have an idea how to implement it plz let me know

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get basic geo-location functionality working in an Activity.  While it's good to have it separated out into a Service, why not just register a location listener in your Activity as a first step?  See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274500/getting-geolocation-after-20-seconds/30275019#30275019  And if you want to use Google Play Services, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191047/access-coarse-location-permission-gives-a-cell-tower-precision-on-android/30315009#30315009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to Dainel i found out how it works ! 
For the people having the same problem as me just use google play services using this code from this link 
 [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission gives a cell tower precision on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191047/access-coarse-location-permission-gives-a-cell-tower-precision-on-android/30315009#30315009)

and to make it as a service just use the intent on the main this way :

```
Intent GPSt = new Intent(this, yourClassName.class);
        startService(GPSt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest, I'm not too familiar with the GPSTracker, but I would at least recommend changing

> ```
> public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     this.location = location;
>     getLatitude();
>     getLongitude();
> }
> ```

From what I gather, the "arg0" is the updated location and never used in the method. I would recommend changing it to.

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {
     this.location = currentLocation;
     getLatitude();
     getLongitude();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest you try restructuring the GPS portion of your code? There is a new Location API that is much easier to use than LocationManager and is not fraught with so many implementation concerns.

[Fused Location Provider API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) manages concerns like Power Management for issues surrounding battery. A good example is located on [Github](https://github.com/leachad/buuteeq-ponyhax)